# How to calculate yesterday created records with today?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db

Hi I would like to know how to calculated records which was created yesterday at some time and calculate with today produced records.
please look my code.

```
   FOR EACH womf_worder OF sfcf_au_ship WHERE womf_worder.word_production_status = "B"
                                 AND womf_worder.word_build_date = DATE(TODAY)    
                                 AND womf_worder.word_build_time GE  tt_shift.shft_start_hour
                                 AND womf_worder.word_build_time LE tt_shift.shft_stop_hour NO-LOCK: 

     IF AVAILABLE womf_worder THEN DO: 
         i = i + 1.         
     END.
```

tt_shift.shft_start_hour = 06:00:00 and stop_hour = 23:50:00

Here my question is   how can calculate records which will be produced by tomorrow with yesterday records. How can i use DATETIME for this?

Comment: You mean like work_build_date = date( today ) - 1 ?

Comment: Yes..exactly..will that work? if not then see above codes , alternate as your wish to get yesterday records with today

Comment: today is already a date, you don't need a date function. today - 1 is yesterday

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "calculate". What @StefanDrissen suggests may be the answer, but it depends on how word_build_date is populated... Further, I think your tt_shift fields could be called out in the WHERE clause or in IF statements. I think we need more detail to assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for each womf_worder of sfcf_au_ship where 
         womf_worder.word_production_status EQ "B"                      and 
         womf_worder.word_build_date        EQ today - 1                and 
         womf_worder.word_build_time        GE tt_shift.shft_start_hour and
         womf_worder.word_build_time        LE tt_shift.shft_stop_hour  
         no-lock: 

    assign i = i + 1.
end.
```

Notes:

1. Function "today" returns a datetype value, dont need casting date();
2. Use expression "today - 1";
3. Don't need "if avail" condition for "for each" blocks, if AVM finds any record, it aways avail;

Answer (score 4):

DATETIME would be very usable if any field in the database is DATETIME. A quick lock at your example makes me think you have separate date and time fields. I'm unsure what the TIME field is. Perhaps an integer or a string?

You don't need the availability check in a FOR-loop. It's for FINDS and possibly JOINS where a record might not be available in the loop. For a basic FOR EACH like that only available records will be processed.

If the time is indeed an integer or a string your code could very well work with a minor fix for the availability check.

```
   FOR EACH womf_worder OF sfcf_au_ship WHERE womf_worder.word_production_status = "B"
                                 AND womf_worder.word_build_date = DATE(TODAY)    
                                 AND womf_worder.word_build_time GE tt_shift.shft_start_hour
                                 AND womf_worder.word_build_time LE tt_shift.shft_stop_hour NO-LOCK: 

         i = i + 1.         
     END.
```

Comment: Time is integer field.Now Can you show me how to use DATETIME in this?

Comment: If time as one field and date is another field you wont have any great use of the DATETIME construct.

Comment: so there is no way to calculate yesterday records with today produced records by giving time as one field and date is another field?

Comment: then change the code as your wish for calculate the yesterday records with today